# Apply advanced filter after autofilter

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I want to do two successive filtering; the first on dates which I use auto-filter and on the produced result I want to do advance-filter (because I have OR in mind).
So what I did first was to set a range variable to the unfiltered range.

```
Set rng = Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(rowNos, colNos))
```

Then using auto-filter I filter for given dates.

```
rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & lDate
```

Since now some rows will be hidden, and I want to apply advanced filter, I made use of specialcells

```
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=crt, CopyToRange:=thisWB.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1"), _
    Unique:=False
```

However I got an error in the last step "the command requires at least two rowa of data . . " I made sure that there were at least 100 rows which fit the criteria meaning that the error is not because of a lack of rows.

Please help me get the problem. Also if there's another way I can accomplish the task I'll be happy to change my codes. What I'm trying to do is for specific dates filter a table and then filter again for values on two columns (as is normally done with advanced filters).

Comment: did the two-step process below work @medwatt?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `.AdvancedFilter` does not work on non-continuous ranges. The code below is a bit kludge-y, but worked for a little example I pulled together where I want to return observations that are > April 1st, 2014 where Foo = Yes and Bar = 7. My data sheet contains exactly one row that matches all those criteria.

[image: setup]

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterTwice()

Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet, _
    ControlSheet As Worksheet, TempSheet As Worksheet
Dim DataRng As Range, ControlRng As Range, _
    TempRng As Range
Dim lDate As Date
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

'assign sheets for easy reference
Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ControlSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

'clear any previously-set filters
Call ClearAllFilters(DataSheet)

'assign data range
LastRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(1, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

'assign a control (or critieria) range for the advanced filter
Set ControlRng = Range(ControlSheet.Cells(1, 1), ControlSheet.Cells(2, 2))

'apply date filter
lDate = "4/1/2014"
With DataRng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & lDate
End With

'add a temporary sheet and copy the visible cells to create a continuous range
Set TempSheet = Worksheets.Add
DataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
TempSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

'assign temp range
LastRow = TempSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol = TempSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
Set TempRng = Range(TempSheet.Cells(1, 1), TempSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

'apply advanced filter to temp range and get obs where foo = yes and bar = 7
With TempRng
    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=ControlRng, _
        CopyToRange:=TargetSheet.Range("A1"), Unique:=False
End With

'remove the temp sheet and clear filters on the data sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TempSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
DataSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub

Sub ClearAllFilters(cafSheet As Worksheet)
    With cafSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode = True Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```